# Sticky page header doesn't stick to top of page

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/sahandz/pen/BrYGKa

I'm making a website where I want a sidebar, header and search bar to be fixed while the results of the search are scrollable. I'm using React, but the rendered HTML looks like this:

```css
.topdiv {
  max-height: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.topdiv h1 {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

@media (max-width: 766px) {
  .container-fluid {
    height: 1200px;
  }
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  top: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: solid;
  padding: 0px;
}

.noofpeople {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.noofpeople-wrapper input {
  width: 55px;
}

.dinneroverview {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.dish-overview-header {
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-top: solid;
  height: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #d4d5d8;
}

.dish-name {
  float: left;
}

.cost {
  float: right;
}

.dinneroverview-price {
  color: red;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.dinneroverview-pricetag {
  float: right;
}

.confirm {
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

@media (max-width: 766px) {
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40%;
    position: static;
    display: none;
    background-color: #e5e6e8;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .confirm {
    padding-top: 40px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .sidebar {
    display: block !important;
    border-right: solid;
    height: 100% !important;
  }
  #hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
  .hamburgerdiv {
    display: none;
  }
  .menuitem {
    width: 270px;
    left: 20px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .confirm button {
    width: 30px;
  }
}

.dishsearch .keyword {
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.dishsearch .select {
  padding: 0px;
}

.dishsearch .search {
  padding: 0px;
}

.searchbar {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
}

.main-bar {
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  right: 0px;
}

.dishsearch {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: solid;
  position: sticky;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
}

.dishsearch-dish {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.dishreel {
  top: 196px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.imgframe {
  width: 146px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: solid;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

.dishsearch-img {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .main-bar {
    width: calc(100% - 297px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="App">
    <header class="App-header">
      <div class="topdiv">
        <h1 class="App-title">Dinner Planner</h1>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="SelectDish">
      <div class="Sidebar" id="sidebar">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 sidebar collapse">
          <div>
            <div class="noofpeople">
              <div class="row noofpeople-wrapper">
                <label>People <input type="number" min="0" id="numberOfGuests" class="form-control"></label></div>
            </div>
            <div id="dinneroverview" class="dinneroverview">
              <div class="dish-overview-header"><span class="dish-name">Dish name</span><span class="cost">Cost</span></div>
              <div id="sidebar-dishes"></div>
              <div class="dinneroverview-price">
                <span id="sidebar-total-price" class="dinneroverview-pricetag">SEK 0.00</span>

              </div>
              <div class="confirm"><button id="confirm" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Confirm Dinner</button></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Dishes" id="dishSearcher">
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 main-bar">
          <div class="row dishsearch">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <h4>Find a dish</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 keyword">
              <input type="text" id="searchbar" class="form-control" value=""></div>
            <div id="dishsearcher-select" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 select">
              <select id="select" class="form-control">
                    
                  </select>

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 search">
              <button id="search-button" type="button" class="btn btn-default">search</button>

            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="dishreel" id="dishreel">
            <div class="dishsearch-dish handhover">
              <div id="dish.id" class="imgframe">
                <img src="https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/cabbage-salad-with-peanuts-723984.jpg" class="dishsearch-img" alt="img">
                <p>Cabbage Salad with Peanuts</p>

              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="dishsearch-dish handhover">
              <div id="dish.id" class="imgframe">
                <img src="https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/Garlicky-Pasta-with-Swiss-Chard-and-Beans-482788.jpg" class="dishsearch-img" alt="img">
                <p>Garlicky Pasta with Swiss Chard and Beans</p>

              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="dishsearch-dish handhover">
              <div id="dish.id" class="imgframe">
                <img src="https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/Slow-Cooker-Vegetarian-Chili-with-Butternut-Squash-482574.jpg" class="dishsearch-img" alt="img">
                <p>Slow Cooker Vegetarian Chili with Butternut Squash</p>

              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="dishsearch-dish handhover">
              <div id="dish.id" class="imgframe">
                <img src="https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/Beef-Liver-with-Fig--Bacon-and-Caramelized-Onion-Compote-[or-the-ultimate-beef-liver-]-551452.png" class="dishsearch-img" alt="img">
                <p>Beef Liver with Fig, Bacon and Caramelized Onion Compote [or the ultimate beef liver ]</p>

              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="dishsearch-dish handhover">
              <div id="dish.id" class="imgframe">
                <img src="https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/steak-potato-kebabs-with-creamy-cilantro-sauce-for-two-695646.jpg" class="dishsearch-img" alt="img">
                <p>Steak &amp; Potato Kebabs with Creamy Cilantro Sauce for Two</p>

              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="dishsearch-dish handhover">
              <div id="dish.id" class="imgframe">
                <img src="https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/Roasted-vegetable---feta-tostada-222482.jpg" class="dishsearch-img" alt="img">
                <p>Roasted vegetable &amp; feta tostada</p>

              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="dishsearch-dish handhover">
              <div id="dish.id" class="imgframe">
                <img src="https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/blackened-salmon-tacos-with-cilantro-yogurt-sauce-551484.jpg" class="dishsearch-img" alt="img">
                <p>blackened salmon tacos with cilantro yogurt sauce</p>

              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="dishsearch-dish handhover">
              <div id="dish.id" class="imgframe">
                <img src="https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/Three-Bean-Greek-Kale-Salad-609091.jpg" class="dishsearch-img" alt="img">
                <p>Three Bean Greek Kale Salad</p>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="dishsearch-dish handhover">
              <div id="dish.id" class="imgframe">
                <img src="https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/Cedar-Planked-Salmon-with-Fresh-Sorrel-Sauce-610524.jpg" class="dishsearch-img" alt="img">
                <p>Cedar-Planked Salmon with Fresh Sorrel Sauce</p>

              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="dishsearch-dish handhover">
              <div id="dish.id" class="imgframe">
                <img src="https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/liver-and-onions-w_-gravy-2-146557.jpg" class="dishsearch-img" alt="img">
                <p>Liver and Onions W/ Gravy</p>

              </div>

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

To my great frustration, the header, with the text "Dinner Planner" doesn't stick to the top. I've tried a bunch of combinations of `fixed` and `sticky` elements, but nothing does the trick. How can I make the header stick to its position when scrolling just like the sidebar and the search bar?

Comment: I wouldn't use float - can cause weird behaviour and probably the cause behind the weird positioning - use `%` to mark out widths and `display: inline-block` to make inline - it's more explicit than float so doesn't cause weird behaviour (if I'm wrong someone let me know ^.^)

Comment: In CSS, replace ".topdiv" with "header.App-header". Check this pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eMVQjM

Comment: how did you try `fixed`? Because if i take your code and only replace `sticky` by `fixed` for `.topdiv`, it stays on top as expected. (even if i would expect this style on `App-header` instead)

Comment: Kaddath, the problem is that the elements "collapse" if I do that, meaning they stop taking up height in the page and the search results are placed under them.

Comment: @besciualex , it works in the code pen, but when I change it in my react project, the same problem persists...

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs , where do you mean I'm using float? the only place I'm using it is within the sidebar for unrelated stuff.

Comment: Sorry but i have no idea what you are talking about, can you precise? I see no element collapsing when i changed to `fixed`. By the way, a `fixed` element goes out of the flow, it keeps its height, but out of the page flow, this is expected. But actually, i saw no change of this kind when i tried. And usually, for fixed elements on top, a simple top margin in the page would fix this behaviour.

Comment: @Sahand you have 3 classes using float in your css ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this picture:
[image]

This is what you want, right?
Basically you have four divs. Three are fixed (top-header, search bar and side bar), and the last one (search-results) is relative. Start with this in mind, then create the HTML structure, then the CSS. Please take a look at the next simple example:

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#top-header{
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
#side-menu{
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
#search-bar{
    background-color: #00ff00;
  color: #000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 200px;
  right: 0;
  top: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 100;
}
#search-results{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
  height: 1500px; /*remove me*/
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top:150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="App">
    <header id='top-header'>
        top header
    </header>
    <div id='side-menu'>
      side bar
    </div>
    <div id='search-bar'>
      search bar
    </div>
    <div id='search-results'>
      search results
    </div
  </div>
</div>
```

You will scroll only inside search results, as you want. Using this simple example you can update your CSS code.

Use `position: fixed;` to make them stay fixed, and the relative container push it down using `margin-top` and `margin-left`. Make sure that the `z-index` value on the fixed elements is greater than the one in relative element.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background: #fff;
}
```